# How do I test theme toggler with react testing library and jest?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am trying to test whether the bg color changes after clicking the theme toggler.

```
test("Toggle changes from light to dark mode", () => {
  render(<DashboardPage />);
  const themeToggler = screen.getByRole("button");
  const dashboardBackground = screen.getByTestId("dashboard-menu");

  expect(themeToggler).toBeInTheDocument();
  expect(dashboardBackground).toHaveStyle(
    "background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255)"
  );
  userEvent.click(themeToggler);
  expect(dashboardBackground).toHaveStyle("background-color: rgb(0,0,0)");
});
```

I have wrapped my components with ThemeProvider, but the background-color remains white even after clicking.

Comment: Can you add your `DashboardPage` component base code? with the code where you do the theme change?

Comment: Hey @LuisPauloPinto. I eventually kind of found a solution, I just emulated changing from light to dark mode in the test with a mock theme toggle function, and by rendering and wrapping again the component with the updated value in the themeprovider. That's the only way I managed

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `@testing-library/user-event`, when you should use `async` functions and wait until user similated events ends up

```
test("Toggle changes from light to dark mode", async () => {
  render(<DashboardPage />);
  const themeToggler = screen.getByRole("button");
  const dashboardBackground = screen.getByTestId("dashboard-menu");

  expect(themeToggler).toBeInTheDocument();
  expect(dashboardBackground).toHaveStyle(
    "background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255)"
  );
  await userEvent.click(themeToggler);
  expect(dashboardBackground).toHaveStyle("background-color: rgb(0,0,0)");
});
```

Comment: Thank you @Yoskutik 
I tried before posting but It doesn't work either